# MSE giving negative results in High-Level Synthesis

Tags: pow, fixed-point, test-bench, mse, vivado-hls

I am trying to calculate the Mean Squared Error in Vitis HLS. I am using hls::pow(...,2) and divide by n, but all I receive is a negative value for example -0.004. This does not make sense to me. Could anyone point the problem out or have a proper explanation for this??

Besides calculating the mean squared error using hls::pow does not give the same results as (a - b) * (a - b) and for information I am using ap_fixed<> types and not normal float or double precision

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an overflow and/or underflow issue, meaning that the values reach the sign bit and are interpreted as negative while just be very large.

Have you tried tuning the representation precision or the different saturation/rounding options for the fixed point class? This tuning will depend on the data you're processing.

For example, if you handle data that you know will range between -128.5 and 1023.4, you might need very few fractional bits, say 3 or 4, leaving the rest for the integer part (which might roughly be `log2((1023+128)^2)`).

Alternatively, if `n` is very large, you can try a moving average and calculate the mean in small "chunks" of length `m < n`.

p.s. Getting the absolute value of `a - b` and store it into an `ap_ufixed` before the multiplication can already give you one extra bit, but adds an instruction/operation/logic to the algorithm (which might not be a problem if the design is pipelined, but require space if the size of `ap_ufixed` is very large).